# Opportunity Stage "Walkthrough"

Tags: opportunity

I remember that about a year ago I read about something that you can do with opportunities. As the user progresses through the different stages, the fields that need to be filled in during a specific stage were highlighted to them on a different screen.
Could you please let me know what this functionality is called and how it can be implemented?
Rgds, Lily

Answer (score 0):

You could use a validation rule to fulfil that purpose. Failure to adhere will populate an error message where you can specific which fields need populating.

Example:

```
OR(
AND(
IF(ispickval(Stage, "Open"),
OR(
isblank(Customer_Comments__c),
isblank(Next_Update__c)
)
),
AND(
IF(ispickval(Stage, "Pending"),
OR(
isblank(Customer_Comments__c),
isblank(Next_Update__c),
isblank(Discussion_Topics__c)
)
)
)
```

Another potential option is to use a different page layout which is assigned dynamically based on the stage which has different mandatory fields (caveat - not something I've done myself, only heard of).

Comment: Hello, yes, I currently do that. I am sure this was something graphical. It looked really cool.